# Json in Listview WICKET

Tags: java, html, json, listview, wicket

HomePage.java

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public HomePage()
{

    new JsonTable("table"); //prints json from database in console- {"schema":[{"name":"George","id":"101"},{"name":"David","id":"102"}]}

    //get JSON here and display it in ListView
    List userList = Arrays.asList(
            new User[] {
                new User("FirstA", "LastA"),
                new User("FirstB", "LastB"),
                new User("FirstC", "LastC")
              });

    add(new ListView("listview", userList) {
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            User user = (User) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("firstname", user.getFirstname()));
            item.add(new Label("lastname", user.getLastname()));
        }
    });

}
}

public class User {

String _first, _last;

public User(String _first, String _last) {
    this._first = _first;
    this._last = _last;
}

public String getFirstname() { return _first; }
public String getLastname() { return _last; }
}
```

HomePage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body> 
<div class="panel panel-default">

<div class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
<table class="table">
<tr wicket:id="listview">
<td><span wicket:id="firstname"></span></td>
<td><span wicket:id="lastname"></span></td>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JsonTable.java

```
public class JsonTable extends BasePage {

public JsonTable(String id) {
    System.out.println("In Constructor");

    String query="select row_to_json(t) from "
            + "(select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t))) as schema from (select name, type from sample) t ) t";
    //System.out.println(query);
    JsonToWidget widget=new JsonToWidget();
    //System.out.println(widget);
    JSONObject json=widget.getJsonForTableContent(query);
    System.out.println(json);

}

 }
```

From HomePage.java and HomePage.html, I am able to print values from Array (in HomePage.java) in HTML Table.
From JsonTable.java, I have successfully retrieved JSON from database but I need to print the JSON in a table.

```
new JsonTable("table"); //in HomePage.java ,prints json in console  -

{"schema":[{"name":"George","id":"101"},{"name":"David","id":"102"}]}
```

I need to parse this and display as `name` and `id` in separate columns in the table.
How can I send JSON to `ListView` in "HomePage.java" through "JsonTable.java" and display in the table?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Wicket based: parse the JSON at the server side and create a List of objects that you should pass to ListView
- JavaScript based: construct the table completely client-side. Wicket is not used in this case.

**Update**: to do it at the server you should use some Java library to deserialize the JSON, e.g. Jackson, GSON, ... With its help you will have a `List<User>` that you can pass to the ListView as you did in your example.

Comment: Thankyou.. I need Wicket Based.. Can you please explain in detail..how to create a List of objects in json to pass to ListView?

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of objects in Json you can use Arrays, arrays in JSON are defined as following, in your case of users should be something like this:

```
[{"firstName":"user1","lastName":"user1LastName"},
 {"firstName":"user2","lastName":"user2LastName"}]
```

Comment: Thankyou.... But my json is -  {"schema":[{"name":"George","id":"101"},{"name":"David","id":"102"}]} . I need to pass these values(name and id) to ListView(in HomePage.java) to display in the table.

Comment: Ok, then you have to create the following things:

Comment: An ArrayList<String,String> in this object you are going to saved the data from the JSON; An XML Layout with two TextView, this XML will represent the layout of each object in the ListView; An adapter, this adapter will call the XML you created previously and put the information that is saved in the ArrayList. When you received the JSON in HomePage.java you have to use a loop for get all elements of the JSON Array. With something like this: JsonArray array = json.getArray("Schema"); for(int i =0;i<json.getSize(); i++){ list.add(array.get(i)); }